# Using an inputField value in a custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-field

I have a custom controller which contains a search function. It is used to search through my custom tree object for a tree based on the users input. I previously had a select list to list the different types of tree but I recently changed it to an input field so I didn't have to type in all 30 types of tree. I am now slightly unsure how to use the value of the input field in my controller.

My visualforce page:

```
<apex:page Controller="TreeSearchController"  >  
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="block" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Criteria">

            <!--The section containing the select list to search by Type -->
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel for="typeSearch">Type</apex:outputLabel>             
                <apex:inputField value="{!trees.Type__c}"  id="typeSearch"/>                
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <!--The section containing the select list to search by Health -->
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel for="healthSearch">Status</apex:outputLabel>             
                <apex:selectList id="healthSearch" value="{!healthSearch}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!healthItems}" />
                </apex:selectList>                    
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <!--The section containing the input text to search by surgeon -->
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel for="surgeonSearch">Surgeon</apex:outputLabel>             
                <apex:inputText id="surgeonSearch" value="{!surgeonSearch}"/>                                      
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>    
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <!--The div containing the search button which is linked to the doSearch method-->
        <div align="center">     
            <apex:commandButton value="Search!" action="{!doSearch}"  />
        </div>
        <!--This section displays the results of the search -->
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Results" id="results" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="t" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(results))}" >
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!t['Id']}">{!t.name}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!t.Type__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{!t.Status__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{!t.Surgeon__r.name}" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>        
</apex:form>
```

My custom controller:

```
public class TreeSearchController {

    String typeSearch;
    String healthSearch;
    String surgeonSearch;
    List<Tree__c> results;
    public Tree__c trees {get; set;}

    //Set and Get for the search by tree type
    public String getTypeSearch() {
        return typeSearch;

    }
    public void settypeSearch(String s) {
        typeSearch = s;
    }

    //Set and Get for the search by Tree Surgeon
    public String getSurgeonSearch() {
        return surgeonSearch;
    }
    public void setsurgeonSearch(String S) {
        surgeonSearch = s;
    }

    //Set and Get for the search by tree Status
    public String gethealthSearch() {
        return healthSearch;
    }
    public void sethealthSearch(String s) {
        healthSearch = s;
    }



    //Create the list options for the Tree type list (probably a better way to do it)
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('Alder (Alnus glutinosa)','Alder (Alnus glutinosa)'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Almond-leaved Willow (Salix triandra)','Almond-leaved Willow (Salix triandra)'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Aspen (Populus tremula','Aspen (Populus tremula'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Common Ash (Fraxinus excelsior)','Common Ash (Fraxinus excelsior)'));

        return options;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> gethealthItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('Healthy','Healthy'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Unhealthy','Unhealthy'));

        return options;
    }

    //get the results of the search
    public List<Tree__c> getResults() {

        List<Tree__c> results = 

            [SELECT Id, Type__c, Status__c, OwnerId, Name, Surgeon__r.name FROM Tree__c WHERE Type__c LIKE :typeSearch AND Status__c LIKE :healthSearch AND Surgeon__r.name LIKE :surgeonSearch]; 


        return results;
    }

    //references the command button on the page
    public PageReference doSearch() {
        results = (List<Tree__c>)[FIND :healthSearch RETURNING Tree__c(Status__c)][0];
        return null;     
    }
}
```

On my visualforce page the type search section used to be a select list just like the health search section is now. However because the value has changed to `{!tree.Type__c}` instead of just `{!typeSearch}` I am unsure on how to use this in my controller

Comment: In your WHERE clause replace :typeSearch with :trees.Type__c

Comment: @DougB I think I need to reference trees.Type__c somewhere else in my controller too? im getting an 'Attempt to de-reference a null object ' error

Comment: You will also need to initialise the trees reference e.g. in the controller constructor to `trees = new Tree__c();` to the page can present the `Type__c` field.